# Creating the hyperlink preview in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to create the preview of a hyperlink. I am unable to get any leads about the same. My project is written in Objective C. 
I searched the web and found a few third party libraries which are written in Swift. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out telegram opensource code,they do have preview,but lots of digging will be needed

Answer (score 0):

To generate a hyperlink preview, make sure the link is either at the beginning of a text message, or at the end of the text message. If the hyperlink is in the middle of the text message, iOS won't show a hyperlink preview. Also make sure that the hyperlink starts with http:// or https://.

Comment: I was asking about the method which I can implement to create a preview for hyperlink